# Does security at the nodeJS server matter on GCP Cloud Run?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, https, google-cloud-run

Currently my nodeJS server works over spdy to have https and tls 1.3 only and is deployed on a vm instance on GCP.

Now i want to migrate to GCP Cloud Run and since they already have manages ssl and so on i question myself if i still need spdy or if i can downgrade my node application to a default express server?

How exactly does the security work there? As far as i understand it the data will get encrypted outside my docker container therefore having https nodejs server does not make sense since then it encrypts the already encrypted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can downgrade your nodejs app. The TLS and Encryption is ensure by the Cloud Run infrastructure. The request are encrypted up to your container.

More details [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#tls)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That documentation page you linked there is very useful in general. But i didn't find it in the huge pile of documentation